# Mapping string type property to byte[] in database in EF Code First

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Trying to have a model with key which is string but in database will be represented as byte[].

Is there any way i can do it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct translation from string to a byte array. You have to specify in what encoding the byte array will represent the string.

You can add a non-mapped wrapper property (`TheStringValue` below) that uses a specific encoding to map the string to bytes and vice versa:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public byte[] StringBytes { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string TheStringValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(StringBytes);
        }
        set
        {
            StringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: `[NotMapped]` - NotMapped attribute can be applied to properties of a class. Default Code-First convention creates a column for all the properties which includes getters and setters. NotMapped attribute overrides this default convention. You can apply NotMapped attribute to a property which you do NOT want to create a column in a database table for. [more info](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)